# What is an enriched initial object / terminal object?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, enriched-category-theory

I am sorry if this is a trivial matter, but I was unable to find a reference:

> Let $\cal{V}$ be a Benabou-cosmos. What is the definition of an initial object in a $\cal V$-category $\cal C$?

From the context of $\mathsf{Ab}$-enriched and $\mathsf{Cat}$-enriched categories it seems like the condition is $\mathcal{C}(I,X) \cong *$ for all $X \in \cal C$, where $*$ denotes the terminal object in $\cal V$. But I am unsure (the underlying category is defined in terms of morphisms $1 \rightarrow C(X,Y)$ and not $* \rightarrow C(X,Y)$...). So I kindly ask for a reference. Thank you very much.

Comment: Kelly doesn't explicitly speak about enriched terminal objects in his book, but about weighted limits and the special case of conical limits. If you take the limit over the empty diagram (in which case there is a unique weight), you get the condition that all homs into the object are terminal in V, as you suspected.

Comment: @JonasFrey Thank you very much. I am currently trying to get a grasp of weighted limits, so I didn’t think of computing that (of cause I should have). I would accept this as an answer…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kelly doesn't explicitly speak about enriched terminal objects in his book, but about weighted limits and the special case of conical limits. If define a terminal object $1$ to be a limit over the empty diagram (in which case there is a unique weight), you get the condition that all hom objects $\mathrm{hom}(A,1)$ are terminal in $\mathcal{V}$, as you suspected.